# Responsive navigation bar issues

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I'm having this problem with my responsive navigation bar on my site. For some reason some of my menu items just drop behind the elements on the page instead of floating above them, but for the life of me I cannot work out why!

My site is www.kenttrophies.co.uk

I was wondering if someone could please point me in the right direction as I am baffled!

Below is an image showing my problem when the site's media queries kick in...

[image: my issue right here]

Many thanks for all answers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like undefinedtoken says, however, I would just add the position relative to the main id which is #cssmenu. So just: #cssmenu{ position: relative; z-index:20; }

You should read up on css z-index, as this will help you control what has a view hierarchy in your page. In this case you want your #cssmenu to have a high hierarchy, so you assign a z-index to it ( I just randomly chose 20, but you can choose any number you want).

For example,

header{ position:relative; z-index:1; }
header .title{ position: relative; z-index:2; }

In that case, the header. title will always be above header because it has a higher (meaning more important) z-index. (also, you need to set a position to each item, in order for z-index to work).

Comment: Aha! Thank you. I tried z-index initially and it didn't work, forgot about the positioning. Rookie mistake! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Just add `position:relative` to your `#cssmenu > ul li a`

```
#cssmenu > ul li a{
  position:relative;
}
```